# Struts2 + spring autowiring actions by-name without exposing certain properties

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I am using Struts 2 and Spring autowiring. Right now, the default strategy is set to by-name, but usually we use the constructor and the fallback works to autowire in properties when only one implementing class is available.

There is one property however that I'd like to wire into an action class that has several implementing classes, so I made the Action a java bean, with the properties as fields that can be set. Unfortunately, the only ways that these will be used (apparently) is if they have a public getter/setter, which also exposes them to the type converter at request time. In other words, if a client adds their name to the request as form fields or parameters, Struts will attempt to write those values to them.

So my question is, is it actually possible to use by-name autowiring without exposing properties like that (which may or may not be a security hazard), or am I better off just using XML and defining the Action as an object with scope prototype?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `type converter at request time`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I've tried to clarify that further.

Comment: you can easily tell S2 param interceptor to excludes certain parameters being set in your action class

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually track down the documentation for the [`ParametersInterceptor`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParametersInterceptor.html) which actually lists three ways you can limit what parameters are set by the interceptor.

- Configuring `excludeParams` in the parameter configuration, which is a global regex which applies to all actions (not what I want, also possibly deprecated as it is no longer described in the most recent class docs).
- Setting `excludeMethods` (does the same as the previous, the preferred method for global excludes)
- Implementing [`ParameterNameAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParameterNameAware.html), which is the closest to what I wanted. Here  you can whitelist what parameters are used.

In the end, defining the action as a prototype object in the normal Spring configuration seemed to be the most prudent. Letting the action manage what parameters it has means another place where parameters need to be explicitly white listed every time a change is made.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing... but you can inject into protected and private members. Here is a short example: http://struts2.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Struts2/Adding+Spring+Dependancy+Injection+to+Struts2+Project In this case Test is a protected member.

Comment: @Quaternion I'm not using annotation based config. When I try to just rely on automatic autowiring, it only injects them when they're public. If you use your approach, does it scope the actions properly?